# How to read json file into jmeter using Random csv config

Tags: jmeter

To read this data into jmeter random csv config data.

Sample Json is as below :

```
{
        "key": "COMMUNICATIONS",
        "id": "72ec45ba-f0a1-11e9-81b4-2a2ae2dbcce4",
        "description": "6666666666666666.",
        "name": "***********************",
        "overview": "*************.",
        "subCategories": [
            {
                "key": "PHONES_VOIP_TROUBLESHOOTING",
                "id": "72ec46e6-f0a1-11e9-81b4-2a2ae2d",
                "description": "fix my phone network as it is down.access my voicemails",
                "name": "Phones/VOIP troubleshooting",
                "overview": "fix my phone network as it is down.access my voicemails",
                "support": "Windows, MAC"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what is your need, what you were tying to do to get it & what's your struggle along the way

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the data you want into i.e. `test.csv` file in JMeter's "bin" directory like:

   ```
   COMMUNICATIONS,72ec45ba-f0a1-11e9-81b4-2a2ae2dbcce4,6666666666666666,***********************,*************.,PHONES_VOIP_TROUBLESHOOTING,72ec46e6-f0a1-11e9-81b4-2a2ae2d,fix my phone network as it is down.access my voicemails,Phones/VOIP troubleshooting,fix my phone network as it is down.access my voicemails,Windows, MAC
   ```
2. Add [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) to your test plan and configure it as follows:

   - Filename: `test.csv`
   - Variable Names: `key,id,description,name,overview,subKey, subId,subDescription,subName,subOverview,support`
   - other fields can be left intact

     Once done you can click `Test CSV Reading` button and you should see generated [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) names along with respective values

     [image]
3. Now you can parameterize your JSON payload in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and replace hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables names:

   ```
   {
     "key": "${key}",
     "id": "${id}",
     "description": "${description}",
     "name": "${name}",
     "overview": "${overview}",
     "subCategories": [
       {
         "key": "${subKey}",
         "id": "${subId}",
         "description": "${subDescription}",
         "name": "${subName}",
         "overview": "${subOverview}",
         "support": "${support}"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   [image]
4. That's it, when you run your test you will see that JMeter Variables are replaced with the values from the CSV file in the runtime using i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

   [image]

Going forward just add more entries to the `test.csv` file so each JMeter Thread (virtual user) could pick up a random value on each iteration.

See [Introducing the Random CSV Data Set Config Plugin on JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter/) article for more details.